# Как элементу одного массива присвоить стиль элемента другого массива?

Tags: javascript, html, css, массивы

```
<div class="lamp">
    <div class="optic" id="op_1"></div>
    <div class="optic" id="op_2"></div>
    <div class="optic" id="op_3"></div>
    </div>
<script>
var opt =[document.getElementById('op_1'),document.getElementById('op_2'),document.getElementById('op_3')];
var col =["red","yellow","green","grey"];
var i;
if (true){
    opt[0]=col[0]
}
  else{
    opt[1,2]=col[3]
  }
  opt[i]=style.background.col[i]
</script>
```

Comment: мне просто в цикле надо часто менять цвета, в моем варианте хотелось что бы к id первого массива присваивался цвет второго

Comment: ну так и напишите ``` if (i === 0) { item.style.background = color[1];  }``` В чем сложность то?

Comment: можно конечно и без массивов document.getElementById('op_1').style.background = "red"; но когда перебираешь в цикле множество вариантов и допустим 4 цвета должны постоянно меняться в зависимости от условия, то хотелось что бы код был покороче  т е предпочтительнее массив

Comment: добавил в код проверку на ID ```if (item.id === 'op_1') {
    item.style.background = color[1];
}```

Answer (score 1):

ES5

```
var opt = document.querySelectorAll('.optic');
var color =["red","yellow","green","grey"];

opt.forEach(function(item, i) {
    if (i === 0 || i === 1) {
        item.style.background = color[3];
        return;
    }

    item.style.background = color[i];
});
```

ES6

```
let opt = document.querySelectorAll('.optic');
let color =["red","yellow","green","grey"];

opt.forEach((item, i) => {
    if (i === 0 || i === 1) {
        item.style.background = color[3];
        return;
    }

    item.style.background = color[i];
});
```

То есть мы забираем все элементы по классу, а не по ID отдельно каждый. Проходимся в цикле по массиву. Осуществляем проверку на индекс элемента цикла и выдаем нужный цвет `background`. Переходим на следующую итерацию, если условие выполнено при помощи `return`.

Если условие не выполнено, то присваиваем цвет соответствующий индексу.

Вариант с проверкой на id (также внутри цикла)

```
if (item.id === 'op_1') {
    item.style.background = color[1];
    return;
}
```

Для наглядности можете посмотреть по клику что происходит

```js
let opt = document.querySelectorAll('.optic');
let color =["red","yellow","green","grey"];

opt.forEach((item, i) => {
    item.addEventListener('click', () => {
      if (i === 0 || i === 1) {
          item.style.background = color[3];
          return;
      }

      item.style.background = color[i];
    })
});
```

```html
<div class="lamp">
    <div class="optic" id="op_1">Будет серый</div>
    <div class="optic" id="op_2">Будет серый</div>
    <div class="optic" id="op_3">Будет зеленый</div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Перепроверьте свой ES5 код.Также не забывайте, что итерировать `NodeList` при помощи `.forEach` выйдет не во всех браузерах, перед этим его надо конвертировать в массив.

Comment: @SashaOmelchenko спасибо за поправочку. Исправил. Какие современные браузеры не умеют `NodeList` перебирать `forEach`?

Comment: Фишка в том, что есть не только современные браузеры, вот ИЕ не поддерживает такое, например.

Comment: @Sasha Omelchenko - все IE, или те которые 6, 7, 8, 9. Все, что ниже 10 - это уже не должно поддерживаться никакими разработчиками.

Comment: Судя по https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach ИЕ не поддерживает этот метод вообще. Ну а так то я согласен )